# Ringtone Uri for Dual sim

Tags: android, dual-sim, ringtonemanager

How to get ringtone Uri for SIM 2. Using below code but its returning ringtone for SIM slot 1.

```
Uri ringtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
```